# How can i use pseudo class nth-of-type with a complex selector?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Good time everybody, i have several elements with class 'someclass' and name 'somename', and a complex selector like:

```
.someclass[name="somename"]
```

And i want to add style only to 2nd element. So i try

```
.someclass[name="somename"]:nth-of-type(2) {}
```

but it does not work as it have to work. While if selector is not complex, for example, just:

```
.someclass:nth-of-type(2) {}
```

it works normally. I tried different kind of brackets, but still have this problem. What is a solution?

UPDATE: I was looking for a way to use nth-of-type for elements, that goes not one-by-one.

My code was like:

```
<div class="someclass" name="somename">1</div>
<div class="someclass2" name="somename">2</div>
<div class="someclass" name="somename">3</div>
<div class="someclass" name="somename">4</div>
<div class="someclass" name="somename">5</div>
```

That's why my code does not worked! Finally there are some solutions in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me just as you described.

```css
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  body {
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .someclass {
      height: 200px;
      width: 100px;
      border: 1px solid lightseagreen;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: 10px;
  }

  .someclass[name="somename"]:nth-of-type(2) {
      background: cornflowerblue;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="someclass" name="somename">1.</div>
<div class="someclass" name="somename">2.</div>
<div class="someclass" name="somename">3.</div>
<div class="someclass" name="somename">4.</div>
<div class="someclass" name="somename">5.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Solution for UPDATE

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  body {
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
  }

  .container div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid lightseagreen;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 10px;
  }

  .container div:nth-child(2) {
      background: cornflowerblue;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="someclass" name="somename">1.</div>
      <div class="someclass2" name="somename">2.</div>
      <div class="someclass" name="somename">3.</div>
      <div class="someclass" name="somename">4.</div>
      <div class="someclass" name="somename">5.</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So finally i guessed that my elemens with this selector goes not one-by-one, but also have elements with other classes between them. For example, if we will change string <div class="someclass" name="somename">2.</div> in your example to <div class="someanotherclass" name="somename">2.</div>, this background-coloring does not work anymore. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7L04zvfb/

Comment: So finally this is my jquery solution: $('.someclass[name="somename"]').eq(1).css('display','none');

Comment: Well there is a solution for that in CSS. See the jsfiddle link. Another solution is also in javascript, but I tried to focus on CSS only.  https://jsfiddle.net/6845qs3k/

Comment: Can also be done with jQiery. I put it inside a `<div class="container>` and set the properties `.container div {...}` for all its children which are `<div>` and then took the second child of the container and gave it the unique setting `.container div:nth-child(2) {...}`

Comment: wow great! All these varians are working

Comment: I'm glad for I could helped you! :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: codepen]

I opened CodePen and wrote this

In the HTML section:

```
<div name='blue' class='yellow'>red</div>
<div name='blue' class='yellow'>red</div>
<div name='blue' class='yellow'>red</div>
<div name='blue' class='yellow'>red</div>
```

In the CSS section:

```
.yellow[name='blue']:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

and, as you see in the photo, seems to work fine.

If you need more resources look [here](https://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/complex-selectors/) under the section `Attribute Selectors`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have updated my question. I didn't know that if elements with the same classes and names go not directly one-by-one, i can't use nth-of-type